# Magento2 : How to remove email validation from customer account registration page

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-account

I want to remove this email validation and user can add mobile number in this field .
How to apply this in my custom module..

Please help me...

[image]

Comment: It is email field. Not mobile number field.

Comment: please post your register.phtml code at your question description.

Comment: I put same file in my custom module and remove validate-email':true from email field and change input type = "email"

Comment: @RohanHapani Hi bro..  did you got the answer for this.. please share it here. i need it urgently

Answer (score 4):

All validations are defined in

> Magento2/lib/web/mage/validation.js

You can see **validation-email**

```
"validate-email": [
    function (v) {
        return $.mage.isEmptyNoTrim(v) || /^([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*@([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*\.(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]){2,})$/i.test(v);
    },
    'Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com).'
],
```

Override register.phtml to your theme

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml
```

remove **'validate-email':true** from data-validate

> data-validate="{required:true}"

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
```

Comment: It's not working :(

Comment: "Email" is not a valid email address. From where this  message is executed?

Comment: data-validate is knockout js. All validations are coming from lib/web/mage/validation.js

Comment: You can see all validations in Magento2/lib/web/mage/validation.js file

Comment: how to remove it?

Comment: If not working after removing 'validate-email':true. Try after chnage to 'validate-email':false . Also check you chnages in right file by enable path hint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58444/discussion-between-prince-patel-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: @PrincePatel remove email validation in checkout possible?

Comment: @RakeshDonga Yes, it is possible to remove and change js validation on the checkout page.

Comment: @PrincePatel any reference link available?

Comment: I can't find  validation-email , I am using Magento 2.3

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the above answer you need to change the input type from `type="email"` to `type="text"`, then it will not be validated anymore as email.