# how to make Email not required in Contact us?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.3

i have Magento 2.4 and i need your help to let guests contact me on Contact us page without adding their email.

i tried to make some changes in form.phtml but still the same issue.

thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, consider describing "the same issue". Also did you override: app/design/frontend/VENDER_NAME/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtm and updatet the contact form email template under: MARKETING > Communication > Email Templates?

Comment: Hi, i mean the email still required in contact us form.

Comment: and changed both form.phtml Theme & magento core

Comment: you can try to this reference https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173558/magento2-how-to-remove-email-validation-from-customer-account-registration-pag

Answer (score 0):

So first, do not modify core code because your modifications can be overridden next time you update Magento.
Second, you have to override both the form.phtml -> set the email field as not required, as well as you will have to override the `\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post` class, because validatedParams() is being invoked inside the execute method, which is checking for the '@' inside the 'email' parameter:

```
if (false === \strpos($request->getParam('email'), '@')) {
    throw new LocalizedException(__('The email address is invalid. Verify the email address and try again.'));
}
```

And, because validatedParams() is private, you can not use a plugin, unfortunately.

So, even if on the front-end the input will not be required, the controller is still doing some basic validation for the email field.

If you do not want to have the email field at all, then you could set a value with '@' for it, and make the input hidden.

If you want to give leave the email field but optional, might want to consider creating a different page for the contact-us form, where you could implement all your custom logic, without having to override core classes, which is not recommended.